# How to show image button arranged in two coloumns using ScrollView in android

Tags: android

I want to make an xml file to arrange a lot of image buttons arranged in two coloumns

I have able to make one colomn using linear layout in ScrollView .
but whenever I'm trying to add another LinearLayout to do the right coloumn , It is showing that A ScrollView can have only one direct child .Then how can I fix my problem? 
here is my xml file :

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="114dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >



   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cap_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/exam_a"/>



  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_b"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_b" />

  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_c"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_c" />

  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_d"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_d" />

  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_e"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_e" />

 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_f"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_f"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_g"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_g"
   android:contentDescription="@null" />
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_h"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_h"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_i"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_i" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/cap_j"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_j" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_k"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_k"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_l"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_l"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_m"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_m"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_n"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_n" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_o"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_o"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_p"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_p"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_q"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_q" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_r"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_r" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_s"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_s" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_t"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_t"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />

  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_u"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_u" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_v"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_v"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_w"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_w" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_x"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_x"
  android:contentDescription="@null" />
  <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_y"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_y" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/cap_z"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/exam_z" 
  android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView can only have one direct child, but that child can have children.
So, make the child of the ScrollView a horizontal LinearLayout, that contains two vertical Linear Layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="114dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cap_a"
                .../>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cap_b"
                .../>
            ...

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cap_a2"
                .../>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cap_b2"
                .../>
            ...

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```